# Run time creation of <li> element dynamically

Tags: jquery

How can I create a list of `<li>` elements with their dynamic values at run time?

Comment: `var li = $('<li />');`

Comment: can you add more details.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Give details, so we can help you

Comment: If you really need to get the answer, please clarify. It seems pretty straight forward question but you are making us confused

Comment: Try this: `$('ul').append('<li></li>');`

Answer (score 4):

```
var array = [1,2,3,4]; //Array to iterate

var lis = $.map(array, function(n, i) {
    return '<li>'+ n +'</li>'; //You can add anything in your li 
});
 $('UL_SELECTOR').append(lis.join("\n")) //UL_SELECTOR means where you want to append
```

Comment: nice and helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [Knockout](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) library. You need to create a model and bind the model to your HTML element at run time. It's very easy to use and has an excellent online tutorial.

It's a clean way of development using the MVVM pattern.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: seats">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li >
</ul>
```

Comment: A library for creating some `li` at runtime?

Comment: @Lenin It's much cleaner and more professional way to develop. You can send the JSON to the front end and bind the model to the view. Sure, you don't feel the advantage when it's just a list right now, but what about when it gets bigger?